# IF in sharepoint 2010

Tags: if-statement, sharepoint-2010, formula, calculated-columns

I create new column call "Normalization". It's Calculated filed(calculation based on other columns)

I try this formula:

> =IF([Probability]="High",[Expected annual savings]*1,IF[Probability]="Low",[Expected annual savings]*0.25)

but it only shows "NO" in the field

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
=IF([Probability]="High",[Expected annual savings]*1,IF([Probability]="Low",[Expected annual savings]*0.25,""))
```